# PHP call inner class parents method without extending parent

Tags: php, class, parent, overloading

is it possible to call a parents method in a child class witch is not extended to its parent? I have something like that:

```
<?php

class wrapper {

    private $inner;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->inner = new inner();
    }

    // this will never get called :(
    public function foo() {
        echo "foo called in parent";
    }

    public function bar() {
        return $this->inner->bar();
    }

    public function getOtherStuff() {
        return $this->inner->blafasel;
    }
}

class inner { // would only be created in class wrapper, never outside

    public $blafasel;

    public function __construct() {
        // do something
        $this->blafasel = "other stuff";
    }

    public function bar() {
        // do stuff
        echo "bar called in inner";

        $this->foo();  // fatal error, method not declared
        parent::foo(); // fatal error, class has no parent
        // ??
        return "something"
    }
}

$test      = new wrapper();
$something = $test->bar();

?>
```

please dont ask why i've not using `class inner extends wrapper`. i have to use it like this cause of old stuff and other required things. So is it possible to call wrapper::foo without beeing static? wrapper is using some public variables of inner and stuff.
I've tried to add `$this` when calling the constructor of inner but that results only in an memory overflow or just a reflection of wrapper.
So is it possible to call wrapper's foo() method in inner'b bar() or do i have to rewrite the whole thing so it could be using extended classes? I know i have to rewrite it but it would take weeks and i need this thing.. well.. yesterday.

Thanks for any help/hints/corrections :)

## EDIT

There are more of `inner` classes that would be called in wrappers constructor, and all have (sort of) the same methods but do different stuff, depends on the inner class itself. (whole code is too long, even for pastebin)

some snippets:

```
class wrapper {
    public function __construct($loadclass=1) {
        if($loadstuff==1)
            $this->inner = new inner();
        else
            $this->inenr = new otherinner();
    }
}
```

and then

```
class otherinner {
    public function bar() {
        // doing different stuff than inner::bar()
        // but call wrappers foo() may with possible args
    }
}
```

i hope this will clear the "why not using extends"

Comment: Your 'Inner' class extends no class therefore what does it inherit? Check documentation before asking

Comment: You are not looking for `parent::foo()`, since the wrapper is not a parent. Actually there is no connection whatsoever from the inner to the wrapper class in your example. You have to inject something in this case, so hand over either a reference to the containing object (wrapper) or to its method when you call `inner::foo()`. But frankly, this smells of bad design.

Comment: I am not sure if [php traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) is useful here. To related both class you will need to use either `extend` or `use`.

Comment: @KyleThomas the `inner` class inherits nothing, it could be standalone, but will never get called as standalone in this project.

Comment: @arkascha thats the exact problem, there is no connection between those two classes, except wrapper knows something of inner, but inner nothing of wrapper - already tried with injecting $this in the constructor but no success

Comment: Inner is an injection for the wrapper not an extension, therefore it doesn't inherit the wrappers methods. It's easier to read documentation on extends @UnskilledFreak

Comment: Stating something like "tried with injecting $this" does not help at all. Be _specific_, be _precise_, _show that attempt_. How else do you expect us to help?

Comment: @Jigar yes the future plan is to use extend, but i need a "fast fix" for this. traits wont work cause foo() will use other things aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Inner extends Wrapper {

    public function __construct() {
         parent::foo();
    }

}

new Inner();
```

Your current wrapper expects an injection of the inner object, this wrapper is now a partial object which inner will complete or **extend**

By extending a partial class, the extension class inherits the partial class. Without an extension, there is no 'parent'.

You are simply using wrapper as a dependency injection in your code, not as an extension.

Comment: as i said, i know how extends, traits and namespaces work, but in this case there cant be an extend - old classes just calling the wrapper with n args and it splits the mess into own inner classes, for sharing identical functions i already using traits and it works perfect, but not the "outsided" functions

Comment: You jus answered your own question, its not possible.. To inherit a classes methods, it must be a partial class and extended. You are using dependency injection so you can't use 'parent', you have to make each method public and call if from the instant ($this->inner->bar(); or self::foo();) @UnskilledFreak

Comment: accepted your answer cause its the way things should be done without "haxing" around. Thank you!

Comment: Well, you could of used reflection or dependency injection just in this case, you are using a wrapper not a container so its best to extend its functionality.

Comment: You are right, but reflections for example doesnt make the code more readable. Extending is the best solution for this kind of use case.

Comment: Reflection isn't unreadable if you created a container for it, see [this example](https://3v4l.org/GEiJJ).